# Why do circularly connected springs have a mode with zero frequency?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spring, coupled-oscillators

I saw that problem with spring connected circularly and found that for one of the normal mode frequency is zero, and could not explain why.

Comment: That sounds like a uniform translation.

Comment: @garyp: your answer is right. I explained it a bit more.

Comment: Hint: Solve for the modes, not just the frequencies. Then it will be completely obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zero frequency mode corresponds to a *merry-go-round* of masses rotating in the same direction. No springs are being stretched/compressed so there is nothing (apart from friction of course) to stop and reverse the motion of the masses.